# How can I connect morphia annotation classes via maven?

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, morphia

I use this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xyz.morphia.morphia</groupId>
    <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But my IDE still shows that it can't import `xyz.morphia.annotations.Reference` and `xyz.morphia.annotations.Index`. What is correct maven dependency for these annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need entityscanner but the correct artifactId is `core`.  There's a docs bug there that I'll correct soon.

Comment: It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I've solved it:

`<dependency>
                <groupId>xyz.morphia.morphia</groupId>
                <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xyz.morphia.morphia</groupId>
            <artifactId>entityscanner-plug</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xyz.morphia.morphia</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: the first entry doesn't point to anything for what it's worth.  `core` is what you want.